# Azure DevOps: Version variable type

Tags: azure-devops

What is the syntax to perform type casting for variables in Azure DevOps?

This article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=vsts - suggests there's a "Version" type and mentions a function which would interpret it as a string would resolve it in major.minor.build format but how do you infer a variable as a "Version" type in the first place? And how do you pull out the individual aspects (i.e. major, minor, build, etc.) from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [types definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=vsts#types), you can see that the type can be *guessed* by the notation. For instance, if it's wrapped in `''`, it is a string. Or, if it starts

> with a number and contain two or three period `(.)` characters

it is of type `Version`.

Regarding the [typecasting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=vsts#type-casting), it says that `Version.TryParse` is used. So, if you read this variable in e.g. PowerShell and try to case to `Version` type, I would expect it to work.

Comment: That makes sense with the pattern based type inference - thanks! However I'm having some trouble with the typecasting. I'm looking to perform this cast within a Custom Condition in the Control Options. Unfortunately my variable that I pass through is still interpreted as a string despite being 1.0.0.5 (for example) and fails the comparison check against a statically entered "minimum version" - any ideas on this?

Comment: Ignore the above, I just had my comparison check in the wrong order!